# recyclwiev content is not visible

Tags: kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pGJD.png)

When I run the application on the emulator, the plugins in the recyclerview do not appear. How can I solve this problem?

When I run the application on the emulator, the plugins in the recyclerview do not appear. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve] for tips on writing a question that will get the answers you are looking for. At this point, you need to debug your code by either adding logging statements or using the Android Studio debugger.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: post your code then only find the solution